# Shell: How do I run a shell script from a directory above on multiple files

Tags: shell

I have the following file directory

```
/home/aero/airplane/case1
/home/aero/airplane/case2
..
/home/aero/airplane/casex
```

I have a shell script that performs some simple commands. I don't want to "cd" into each directory and run the shell script (runscript.sh). Is there a way to run it in a simpler fashion, where I type something along the lines of:

```
runscript.sh /case*
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a second script that run `runscript.sh` with all the cases:

```
#In the new shell run every case
runscript.sh /home/aero/airplane/case1
runscript.sh /home/aero/airplane/case2
..
runscript.sh /home/aero/airplane/casex
```

Comment: The issue with this approach is that you have to create a second script, this consumes time and is specific to the cases listed in that second script. I have seen commands (that I can't remember now) that are able to run a script using a wild card argument (case*).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

Create a file named runscript.sh inside /home/aero/airplane

```
#!/bin/bash
MAINPATH=/home/aero/airplane
CHILD_DIR=$(ls | grep -v runscript.sh)

for i in $MAINPATH
do 
    cd $MAINPATH/$i 
    pwd
    cd ..
done
```

Run:

```
sh runscript.sh
```

See that the script enters all the directories running it a single time.

Now, you can change the "pwd" line to do whatever you want inside all the directories.

Comment: I'm looking for something more direct. I know how to submit my shell script using the following: 'cd case1 ; runscript.sh' I would love to be able to type  'cd case* ; runscript.sh' and the script would be able to run for all case directories. I want other users to be able to run this without having to setup extra files/shells

Comment: I think I got what you need, but I don't think it's possible to run something natively like: cd case* to run for all cases without you setting it on the main script, in this case, the runscript.sh. The closest to this I can think is to create a routine to do this, within runscript.sh, and create a symbolic link into /usr/bin, or another folder that holds system's binaries and commands, so the script can be used from anywhere. If you explain more of your idea, I probably could be more detailed.